# Programmatically get SSRS Database Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way to programmatically get the Report Server Database name.
I can open the Object Explorer in Server Management Studio, and see the database in there, however, ideally I need to get this via code and have it returned to a variable so I can use it later on in my query to grab data from a view within that database, in case the report server database name ever changes, thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't understand your Q well, are you refering to `select db_name()`??

Comment: @Sami I believe **select db_name()** would work, but I need it return the name of the database a specific view inside of it, is that possible to do?

Comment: @scsimon if someone went into the properties and changed the name of ReportServer for some reason

Comment: db_name() will return the name set in the datasource not the name of Reportserver database.

Comment: Fair enough @DKerka I think i see where you are going with this now. I put a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using sp_MSforeachdb

```
create table #myDatabases (dbname sysname)

insert into #myDatabases
exec master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; select db_name() where exists (select 1 from sys.objects where name = ''CreateDataDrivenNotification'')'

select * from #myDatabases where dbname is not null

drop table #myDatabases
```

I'd also [read this blog though about this proc](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).  This assumes no user databases has the object (proc in this case) `CreateDataDrivenNotification` which is pretty unique I think. You could check for others to make it more "bulletproof" like `SetDrillthroughReports`

Comment: This may work. But try it by creating a SSRS project and see what you get.

Comment: Can you elaborate @benjaminmoskovits? The OP stated *variable so I can use it later on in my query to grab data from a view within that database*. Nothing about having a RDL automatically discovering what the report server database is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`DB_NAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as:

```
SELECT DB_NAME();
ALTER DATABASE OldName MODIFY NAME = NewName;
SELECT DB_NAME(); --Get the name even after the db name has been changed
```

From the docs online:

> database_id
>   Is the identification number (ID) of the database to be returned. database_id is int, with no default. If no ID is specified, the current database name is returned.

So you may need to pass the `database_id` to get what you want.

eg:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(1) AS DB_Name;
```

Return:

```
+---------+
| DB_Name |
+---------+
| master  |
+---------+
```

Finnaly, the `database_id` can be changed if the db restored or re-created.

Comment: This will return the name of the Database set in the datasource. The question is when is the name of the db the ReportServer db has been changed to.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Yup, only if you don't pass the `database_id` parameter.

Comment: That makes sense and is probably what I've been looking for I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: how would you know the databaseid? Also how would you know the database was the report server versus some random other server?

Comment: Try creating a SSRS project and do what Sami is suggesting. You can guess what database the report server is (what number to put into db_name but its only a guess. If you installed SSRS after/before SSAS etc will determine where the report server db is in the table databases. This is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the database the reports are running against, use `DB_NAME()` like others suggested.

If you are talking about the `ReportServer` database, don't worry - it can't be renamed (or rather, renaming it would break a lot of other stuff).

> Renaming a report server database is not supported because the report server databases are considered internal components.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/administer-a-report-server-database-ssrs-native-mode?view=sql-server-2017#naming-conventions-for-the-report-server-databases))

Comment: do a google search. You can rename a reportserver database. One dba had to do it for a recovery site. You have to edit all the procs and views in the reportserver db to refer to the new name.DB_name() returns the datasource db not the reportserver db.

Comment: I know db_name() returns the datasource db, I wrote that in my answer. 

I'm sure you _can_ rename the reportserver db, but it's specifically not supported by MS, and therefore not a very good idea if you have any sort of support contract.

Comment: MS, unlike Oracle, will support a renamed ReportServer database. The challange (and its an hour or two of careful work) is to find very reference to ReportServer in procs and views and replace it with the new db name.

Comment: Well, they still say in their documentation (linked above) that it's not supported, for SQL server 2017.

Comment: I don't know what official policy is but I have worked on installations that did very unusual things to the SQL Server install and never (unlike other vendors) had MS support declare, "We are not helping you." But this is not guarantee that others will encounter the same cooperation.